# Editable javascript chart - interactively resize bars or pie sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, controls, allocation

I need a library or a framework plugin that can draw charts that can be modified real-time by resizing part of the chart itself. Is there such thing?

I plan to use it for adjusting the chart values. Mostly for controlling amount allocation.

For example. You have 4 hours and you have 5 distinct types of tasks. I want the user to be able to allocate time for each task and see visually what's the impact on the available time.

Comment: Hi, have you found anything worthy? Lot enough charts provide editing support in a form of epxosing certain events, very few - do actually support it. I'm looking for out of box support for dragging control poitns (note, modifying curves using adorners is a different thing). cheers!

Comment: I haven't. May be because it's not very usable. Or there's just none at the moment.

EDIT: There is [one editable pie chart](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch-charts-1.0.0/examples/Pie/) but only works for mobiles and partly works for webkit browsers.

Comment: I know is 2018, but.. did you find anything ? :)

Comment: @Victor nope :)

Answer (score 5):

I think [Visually Editable Charts of Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/demos/gallery/#visually-editable-charts) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

We use various charts from http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ for our web app, and it works great.

The chart are loaded once, and refreshed, each time the user change a value, with new data through their Javascript API in real-time.

Comment: I think you didn't understand completely: **charts that can be modified real-time by resizing part of the chart itself**. I don't wont additional controls. I want the chart to be the control for the data.

Answer (score 1):

gRaphael should be the most popular:

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

I can recommend HighCharts:

http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: I've use highcharts all the time. It's really well made and the documentation for it is superb.

Comment: @nambrot, i don't see the desired functionality. Repeating myself but obviously necessary: **charts that can be modified real-time by resizing part of the chart itself**. I don't wont additional controls. I want the chart to be the control for the data.

Answer (score 1):

Found a few options: http://jamesalvarez.co.uk/uncategorized/draggable-piechart-js-class and http://www.shodor.org/interactivate/activities/PieChart/.
The first one looks the most promising.